# Binding issue while working with ComboBox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, winui-3

I got a problem with `Binding` in `WinUI3`, I don't really understand the source of my problem.

I have defined a `UserControl` named `MyUserControl` in this `UserControl` I just defined a `ComboBox` named `NumberOfPlayers`, like below:

```xml
<ComboBox
    Width="{Binding ElementName=numberOfPlayersStackPanel, Path=ActualWidth}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=NumberOfPlayersCollection}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=NumberOfPlayers, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here is my code-behind:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<int> NumberOfPlayersCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 5, 6, 10 };

public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfPlayersProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(NumberOfPlayers),
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(5));

public int NumberOfPlayers
{
    get => (int)GetValue(NumberOfPlayersProperty);
    set
    {
        // I cant reach to this line.
        SetValue(NumberOfPlayersProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I can't reach to `NumberOfPlayers`'s setter. This is the problem I have with `Binding`.

I can do it with `x:Bind` ofcourse but all my `UserControls` are working with `Binding` except this one (I don't have `ComboBox` on the rest of them).

Comment: Not sure about WinUI, but in WPF a Binding would not result in calling the setter of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The framework would directly call SetValue. In order to get notified about property value changes, you would have to register a PropertyChangedCallback with the PropertyMetadata.

Comment: I agree with @Clemens. One thing that I noticed is that it should be `nameof(NumberOfPlayers)`, not `nameof(NumberOfPlayersProperty)`.

Comment: Yes it was my mistake @AndrewKeepCoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [Custom dependency properties - Implementing the wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties#implementing-the-wrapper):

> In all but exceptional circumstances, your wrapper implementations should perform only the GetValue and SetValue operations. Otherwise, you'll get different behavior when your property is set via XAML versus when it is set via code. **For efficiency, the XAML parser bypasses wrappers when setting dependency properties; and talks to the backing store via SetValue.**

So when a dependency property is set by a Binding the framework does not call the setter of the wrapper property, but instead directly calls the `SetValue` method. In order to get notified about a value change of a dependency property, you have to register a `PropertyChanged` callback with property metadata.

Besides that, you are also using a wrong `name` argument for the Register method. It must be `nameof(NumberOfPlayers)`, not `nameof(NumberOfPlayersProperty)`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfPlayersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(NumberOfPlayers),
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(5, NumberOfPlayersChanged));

public int NumberOfPlayers
{
    get => (int)GetValue(NumberOfPlayersProperty);
    set => SetValue(NumberOfPlayersProperty, value);
}

private static void NumberOfPlayersChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var control = (MyUserControl)obj;
    var newValue = (int)args.NewValue;
    Debug.WriteLine(newValue);
}
```

Comment: tnx for the answer @Clemens, I did what Microsoft said in [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It should be clear that you need a PropertyChanged callback to get notified about property changes.

Comment: tnx for the answer I got it 